# Rails Controllers overriding routes with namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, overloading

I have a Rails app with routes defined with namespace;

routes.rb:

```rb
resources :customers do
  resources :employees do
    # [1] First absence controller
    resources :absences, only: %i{ index new create } do
      # omit verbose
    end
  end
end

scope module: :employee, path: :employee, as: :employee do
  # [2] Second absence controller
  resources :absences, only: %i{ index new create } do
    # omit verbose
  end
end
```

Extract from `rails routes -c absences`:

```sh
                            Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                                                    Controller#Action
reported_customer_employee_absence POST /customers/:customer_id/employees/:employee_id/absences/:id/reported(.:format) absences#reported
        customer_employee_absences GET  /customers/:customer_id/employees/:employee_id/absences(.:format)              absences#index
                                   POST /customers/:customer_id/employees/:employee_id/absences(.:format)              absences#create
     new_customer_employee_absence GET  /customers/:customer_id/employees/:employee_id/absences/new(.:format)          absences#new
            avoid_employee_absence POST /employee/absences/:id/avoid(.:format)                                         employee/absences#avoid
                 employee_absences GET  /employee/absences(.:format)                                                   employee/absences#index
                                   POST /employee/absences(.:format)                                                   employee/absences#create
              new_employee_absence GET  /employee/absences/new(.:format)                                               employee/absences#new
```

All runs as expected in development and test environment.

**But in production environment** the problem it's when it's invoked 'employee/absences' urls, Rails it's running the first [1] not the second [2] controller.

My versions:

```
 Env  | Ruby      | Rails   | Gem
--------------------------------------
 Dev  | 2.5.1p57  | 5.2.3   | 2.7.6
 Test | 2.5.6p159 | 5.2.2.1 | 2.7.6.2
 Prod | 2.3.3p222 | 5.2.3   | 2.5.2.1
```

-- Added later --

Maybe it's a declaration issue:

absences_controller.rb

```rb
class AbsencesController < ApplicationController
end
```

employee/absences_controller.rb

```rb
class Employee::AbsencesController < Employee::ApplicationController
end
```

How `employee/absence_controller.rb` it's the first controller in employee namespace it's having a problem or something like this?

Comment: instead of resources :customers use namespace :customers

Comment: @vishal, customers it's a controller too.

Comment: can you ssh in on the server and run: `rails routes -c absences` ? what does it say?

Comment: @Brainmaniac it's the second code block.

Comment: So that code block is from the server and not local where it works? If so please define where the extract is from. If I understand correctly you are happy with the outcome of the results from rails `routes -c absences` ? The problem occurs when accessing the URL in the browser in production?

Comment: @Brainmaniac Then block it's "rendered" with the same output in all environment. Yes, the problem occurs when rails receive the request.

Comment: The block, sorry.

Comment: Try changing `scope module: :employee, path: :employee, as: :employee` to `namespace :employee`.

Comment: can u post your preffered outcome of: rails routes -c absences